# How to append a centered progress spinner on top of an overlay?

Tags: jquery, css, overlay

I have the following code snippet that basically appends a site overlay which works as required.

The only thing I am not able to do now is how to also show a image progress spinner I have, fixed in the center of the screen over this same overlay. If possible, I would like it to be part of this existing overlay div as I need to issue a `$("#overlay").hide();` to remove the overlay.

I know I need to include a:

```
'background-image: 'url("progress_spinner.gif")'
```

but am unsure how to do and whether I need to append another div to `body`

```
$(function() {
   var docHeight = $(document).height();

   $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");

   $("#overlay")
      .height(docHeight)
      .css({
         'opacity' : 0.6,
         'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=60)',
         'position': 'absolute',
         'top': 0,
         'left': 0,
         'background-color': 'black',
         'width': '100%',
         'z-index': 5000
      });    
});
```

Comment: `background:transparent url(path/to/image) no-repeat center center` ? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Thanks asprin - do I just add it to my existing $("#overlay") div?

Comment: Just add it inside the `.css()` method

Comment: Just tried it but unfortunately it's knocked out my background-color of black and opacity. Could it be b/c this image needs to be on a higher z-index? Are you able to provide a jsfiddle example for me pls. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to do is use the `background` property with the following attributes:

```
.css({
         'opacity' : 0.6,
         'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=60)',
         'position': 'absolute',
         'top': 0,
         'left': 0,
          'background': 'black url(path/to/image) no-repeat center center',   
         'width': '100%',
         'z-index': 5000
});
```

The arguments to that property are:

- Background color
- Path to the image
- Whether to repeat, repeat-x, repeat-y or not repeat the background image
- Left position
- Top position

Alternatively, you could also use the full version:

```
.css({
         'opacity' : 0.6,
         'filter' : 'alpha(opacity=60)',
         'position': 'absolute',
         'top': 0,
         'left': 0,
         'background-color': 'black',
         'background-image': 'url(path/to/image)',
         'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
         'background-position': 'center center',   
         'width': '100%',
         'z-index': 5000
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WE2Wy/2)

Answer (score 0):

If you are showing the overlay on page load, usually you wouldn't need to dynamically create it using client scripts. I would normally include the overlay in the page. Then, you will not need to dynamically create it on page load and show it.

Another note, I would try to avoid using opacity and filters because this will be applied to your background images as well. Try using an RGBA color instead and add a RGB fallback for browsers that don't support it.
To center the background image just use the `background-position` property

Comment: On using an RGBA color as well as a fallback, are you able to provide this info to match my opacity/filter and will also need it work with IE8. Thanks.